# Why WAMP Server deleted my system files?

Tags: php, wamp

I just made a mistake in a PHP application I'm developing with WAMP Server.

My WAMP / WWW folder is inside my D:\ disk, where I also have my personal data. My app, due to a fail in generating a dynamic path, deleted all my music, my photos and other personal files I had.

I mean... WHAT? How was it possible? I will need a recovery tool to recover that data.

How can keep the PHP from touching anything outside it's folder in www so it does not happen again? It's a disaster.

Comment: Use proper permissions on your filesystem, set Apache to run under a specific user with limited access to your filesystem... and generally be very careful when executing code that can delete a whole heap of files? :)

Comment: If the WAMP server is running as *you*, i.e. as the same user that owns all those files, than it can do anything that you can do too. You avoid this by letting it run as a different/less privileged user. I also hope this was a lesson in backing up for you. :-3

Comment: I do it modifying a file? or just right clicking and then changing permissions on the executable?

Comment: Next time create a failsafe?

Comment: Thank you all for relpying. I need a bit of enlightment. How can I modify the permissions for wamp server so it works properly inside its www folder but does not touch anything outside it?

Comment: I'd probably make a restricted user account (with access only to the `DOCUMENT_ROOT`) and then run the server as that user, which I guess you would use [`runas`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490994.aspx) for.

Answer (score 2):

> Limit the files that can be accessed by PHP to the specified directory-tree, including the file itself.

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir

Use `open_basedir` to restrict file operations to within specific directories, like this (in the website's VirtualHost file)...

```
php_admin_value open_basedir "C:/WampDeveloper/Temp/;C:/WampDeveloper/Websites/www.example.com/webroot/"
```

Though if you are deleteing via the command line or bat file (e.g., you are not using PHP file functions directly), the only way to fix this is to set Apache to run under a custom account that only has permissions set on WAMP's folder.

Comment: Nice answer. But be careful, its very easy to make WAMPServer and presumably any Apache/PHP installation completely unusable with this parameter as well.